# mute iframe not working not a youtube iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, mute

I have the following iframe

```
<iframe id="video"
src="http://173.236.41.86/iframe/nagsheadpier.html"   
frameborder="0" 
width="560px" 
height="420px" 
scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

I tried to prevent all sound from coming from this iframe using

```
<script> 
    var myVid=document.getElementById('video'); 
    myVid.muted=true; 
</script>
```

and other variation of this without any progress. Is there any way to do this and if not why. any input would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the code for what's in the iframe? You might have to enable the javascript api on the youtube player (https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference).

Also, if you're accessing your video from the parent frame, you'll have to target the child frame and postMessage something to it (or just do all of it in the child frame)

Comment: My issue is not with youtube's iframe but with iframe in general. I have a link http://173.236.41.86/iframe/nagsheadpier.html but I want to mute it and I haven't seen a solution that works yet.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. I think the best possible solution would be to only show the frame when you absolutely need it to play something.

Comment: you are right about. I had to use another link because I couldn't mute this one.